# Real story vs true story

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

First of all, I would like to know if there is such a word composition as "real story". If there is, I would like to know the difference between "real story" and "true story."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, "real story" does exist. Here are just two examples regarding *true story* and *real story*.

*True story* is often used to say that a story really did happen in real life. You will often see *based on a **true story*** regarding a movie, or you will hear someone say *it's a **true story*** when they say something that seems incredible. I don't think you will often read or hear *real story* in this sense.

*Real story* is often used to say that the story tells the truth, as opposed to other stories that are false about a particular topic. Specifically, you will often see ***the** real story* in this sense. Here is a title I found searching [real story](https://www.google.com/search?q=real+story&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=real+story&tbm=bks) on Google books published in 2001:

> The Race to the Top: The Real Story of Globalization

You can imagine that there have been many books (or so-called stories) written about globalization. But by saying that this story is the *real story*, it suggests that previous books on globalization have been false, incomplete, or in some other way inadequate. But *true story* can be used in this sense too. I don't see a problem with the title

> The Race to the Top: The True Story of Globalization

I think it conveys the same sense as the original.

Comment: Ok I kind of get it /: let's see if I understand. There is the real story of something but there isn't a real story like someone cannot tell me a story about his life and say that's a real story he should say that's a true story. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I would expect "it's a true story", or simply "true story" at the end of a personal story that seems unbelievable. It is possible for the speaker to say "it's a real story", but that sounds strange to me, at least in my experience.

Comment: I understand that every story is a real story but not every story is a true story. Thanks Max.

Comment: @Manuel to a degree the phrases are interchangeable. I think it's common to make the distinction described above, so while I agree with it, and upvoted it, you may not find everyone using the two phrases consistently that way in every situation. It's not the case at all though that "every story is a *real* story" in the way(s) most people would interpret that.

Comment: @shawty00 thanks fo your comment and for teaching me more. Whilst, I say that "every story is a real story" it may not be true depending in the meaning of word real you utter  when you say it or understand when you hear it. I mean I know real means true as well but it's also true that everything that exist is real so every story is a real story if it does exist otherwise it can not be real because it doesn't exist but again only if you see it that way in a different point of view real means true and I asked this question because I often use real in place of true like "real love"